# Infix to postfix Looping

Tags: c

enter code here,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define SIZE 50
char s[SIZE];
int top=-1;   

void push(char elem)
{                  
    s[++top]=elem;
}

char pop()
{                     
    return(s[top--]);  
}

int pr(char elem)
{                
    switch(elem)
    {
        case '#': return 0;
        case '(': return 1;
        case '+':
        case '-': return 2;
        case '*':
        case '/': return 3;
    }
}

void main()
{                       
    char infx[50],pofx[50],ch,elem;
    int i=0,k=0,j;
    for(j=0;j<=3;j++)
    {
        printf("\n\nRead the Infix Expression ? ");
        scanf("%s",infx);
        push('#');
        while( (ch=infx[i++]) != '\0')
        {
            if( ch == '(') 
                push(ch);
            else
                if(isalnum(ch)) 
                    pofx[k++]=ch;
                else
                    if( ch == ')')
                    {
                        while( s[top] != '(')
                        pofx[k++]=pop();
                        elem=pop();
                    }
                    else
                    {      
                        while( pr(s[top]) >= pr(ch) )
                            pofx[k++]=pop();
                        push(ch);
                    }
        }  

        while( s[top] != '#')    
            pofx[k++]=pop();

        pofx[k]='\0';         
        printf("\n\nGiven Infix Expn: %s  Postfix Expn: %s\n",infx,pofx);
    }
}
```

When looping through infix to post fix expression,it's not looping beyond 1st loop.

It is producing output of 1st loop and showing segmentation fault for rest of loops

Please can somebody guide me?

Consider an example

given input,

Given Infix Expn: a+b  Postfix Expn: ab+

Read the Infix Expression ? a-b
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and then [edit] to make sure that the post looks as you intend it to. That would increase readability and your chances for help. As furhter improvement I recommend to apply indentation in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to reset the index for `pofx` and `infx` for every new input. i.e to reset `i` and `k` in the `for-loop`. Fix as below,

```
void main()
{                       
    char infx[50],pofx[50],ch,elem;
    int i=0,k=0,j;
    for(j=0;j<=3;j++)
    {
        i=0;j=0;//here is the update

        //rest of your code follows,

    }
}
```